# Couldn't load the category php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am creating an e-commerce website. I completed the design part. While writing the coding part I ran in to the problem on couldn't display the categories inside the `<div id="categories"><li><li></div>`
I attached the code below what tried so far. there is no error displayed how to display the categories inside the `div` tag.

**All categories display inside to this Div like order list**

```
  <div id="categories">
       <li ><li>
  </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 function getCategory(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'all_category.php' ,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);

                $("categories").html(data.catname);

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
//
            }

        });
    }
```

**Database** **all_category.php**

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id,catname,status from category order by id DESC ");
$stmt->bind_result($id,$catname,$status);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $output[] = array ("id"=>$id, "catname"=>$catname,"status"=>$status);
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
}
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: In ajax you will get the response. Parse the response and make a string variable and then append to the required DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery syntax is slightly off - minor spelling issue;

```
 $("categories").html(data.catname);
```

should be

```
 $("#categories").html(data.catname);
```

**Edit:** to address the issue of the items not being added to your list, you'll need to append the element inside of your ajax's success handler:

```
$.each(data.catname, function(key, value) {
    $("#categories").append('<li>'+ value +'</li>');
});
```

Comment: My answer addresses one of your problems. When you run this, you're still unlikely to get the results you're looking for in the `<li>` tags. If you can edit the question with what a `var_dump()` of `$output` looks like, then I can address the second problem.

Comment: sir i did it what the answer you posted but didn't work sir.

Comment: <li> tag how can i call in to ajex to display the output

Comment: Read my above comment, I'd need to know the output of `$output` in all_category.php

Comment: yes sir. $output  this is a  output in all_category.php

Comment: Obviously... again, I'd need to know what a `var_dump()` of `$output` looks like.

Comment: i made the output as json type sir . data will be success fully display on page. i tested using console.log(data). but how to pass it <li> tage inside the <div>

Comment: I've told you what is needed, I don't know how to explain it any other way. Go back through my responses and see if you can help us help you :)

Comment: 0: {id: 55, catname: "Mobilenew", status: 1}
1: {id: 52, catname: "TV", status: 1}     this is $output i am getting how to pass this output into li tag    i did it like this $("#categories li").html(data.catname); no output displayed

Comment: Let me know if that helps you out, if not, print the console error logs if there are any.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list  this error shown on the console.

Comment: Just posted a final update - but it seems like you could do a little bit of investigate debugging on your end at this point. Hopefully you get the problems resolved.